# Forcing HTTPS from HTTP

Tags: apache-2.2, port

What is the best way to always reroute all traffic from http to https on Apache 2?

All requests to 80 should go to 443.

(I am using Ubuntu + Apache 2)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Forcing HTTPS from HTTP (Apache)](http://serverfault.com/questions/165347/forcing-https-from-http-apache)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You posted [over on ServerFault as well](https://serverfault.com/questions/165347/forcing-https-from-http-apache), and it looks like it has been answered. This is simply to add a solution to this question on SuperUser in the event that someone else is looking for an answer to this question.