# Redirect a subfolder from http to https

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

how can i redirect a subfolder to https e.g http://example.com/vacation-rental/115 to https://example.com/vacation-rental/115

Answer (score 4):

Use this in your vhost definition:

```
<Location /vacation-rental/115>
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
      RewriteRule     (.*)$   https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI}
</Location>
```

Comment: You're like some sort of `mod_rewrite` ninja.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Location /vacation-rental/115>
      SSLRequireSSL
</Location>
```

and see [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/165347/forcing-https-from-http-apache).